# Log the exception in a log file if there is conversion exception

Tags: c#, rhino, yield-return, rhino-etl

I need to log the exception message if any conversion exception comes while iterating data of a file and then continue with next data.

For example, if the input file has 10 records and there is exception raised due to 7th record. Then I need to yield return Rows for 1-6 and 8-10, along with logging exception for 7th record.

I am using the following code to yield rows using data of a file:

```
public override IEnumerable<Row> Execute(IEnumerable<Row> rows)
{
    using (FileEngine file = FluentFile.For<SomeDataRecordETL>().From(FilePath))
    {   
        foreach (object obj in file)
        {
            yield return Row.FromObject(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `FileEngine` may expose an OnError method.  The current FileHelpers library has 3 error modes: `ThrowException`, `SaveAndContinue`, and `IgnoreAndContinue`.  You might be able to use `SaveAndContinue` as part of your solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about exceptions thrown by `FromObject()`, then you can just use `try`-`catch`:

```
foreach (object obj in file)
{
    try
    {
        yield return Row.FromObject(obj);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) // ideally, this should be some specific exception type
    {
        Log(ex);
    }
}
```